# Git Pull a specific sub folder from a specific folder in a specific remote branch

Tags: git

I am trying to pull a specific sub folder from a specific folder in a remote branch

```
git checkout Yakeey_Data/explore -- Notebooks/Source data/CasaArrondVille
```

The name of the remote branch is `explore`. The name of the origin is `Yakeey_Data` It contains many files and folders. One of the folders `Source Data` is not recognized because it is named with a space between Source and Data.

The code gives an error :

```
error: pathspec 'Notebooks/Source' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'data/CasaArrondVille' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

How can i go around this problem and make it recognize the folder without renaming it?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+escape+space

Comment: `git checkout Yakeey_Data/explore -- "Notebooks/Source data/CasaArrondVille"`